# PhpStorm different folder-icons

Tags: icons, phpstorm

In a project one folder is shown as a non-filled folder-icon (see "Destructform"). I do not know why and I do not find any resources on the web about that.

Do you know what's the difference to all the other ("filled") folder-icons (see "D3Client")?

[image: screenshot]
this is Solarized dark theme

[image]
this is intelliJ theme

Comment: What theme are you using? Maybe you are using Material Theme UI plugin or stuff like that .. which changes default icons. Post a screenshot using default native theme (ensure that such extra GUI plugins are disabled).

Comment: Those are custom icons, they do not seem to come from IDE itself. Disable Material Them UI plugin if you have it enabled (looks like you have it; restart IDE after done)

Comment: See https://www.material-theme.com/docs/configuration/icons-settings/#folder-decorators

Answer (score 0):

The folders are filled when there are no files modified inside. If you look at your D3Client folder, you could notice that the folder is up to date with you versioning, and in your Destructform folder there is at least one modified file

Hope it helps.